# How can I assign value to variable declared by Fragment, value from onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-safe-args

I would like to assign value to variable that is declared by Fragment, from the value of position: Int variable set from onBindViewHolder. My strategy is that get the value of position: Int to pass the value assigning for which the item clicked from RecyclerView list and ListHolder's onClick function takes the value for further task.

My source code causes exceptions:

```
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment info.shutterpress.idols.DetailFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception

caused by
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DetailFragment{f172e1b} (89c2cac6-2fcc-45ba-993c-e955b8a8fd6f) has null arguments
```

I think onBindViewHolder does not execute before Fragment's onClick executes, or something is wrong so bind.apply { _position = position } does not work. So, _position is not set and Safe Args does not work and causes the exceptions above.

The source code is as follows:

```
package info.shutterpress.idols

import android.content.res.TypedArray
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import info.shutterpress.idols.databinding.FragmentRecyclerviewBinding

class ListFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var bind: FragmentRecyclerviewBinding
    var title: Array<String>? = null
    var image: TypedArray? = null
    var _position: Int = 0

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        bind = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false)
        title = resources.getStringArray(R.array.idols_title_array)
        image = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.idols_list_image_array)
        var adapter = IdolsListAdapter(image, title)
        bind.idolsList.adapter = adapter
        return bind.root
    }

    inner class ListHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
        var titleTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_item_title)
        var imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_item_image)

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionRecyclerviewFragmentToDetailFragment().setPositionDatum(_position)
            v.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            _position = position
        }
    }

    inner class IdolsListAdapter(var image: TypedArray?, var title: Array<String>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) : ListHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
            return ListHolder(view)
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = title!!.size

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListHolder, position: Int) {
            var mImage = image!!.getResourceId(position, -1)
            var mTitle = title!![position]
            holder.apply {
                titleTextView.text = mTitle
                imageView.setImageResource(mImage)
            }
            holder.bind(_position)
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/main_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:name="info.shutterpress.idols.MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_main_fragment_to_recyclerview_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/recyclerview_fragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_fragment"
        android:name="info.shutterpress.idols.ListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recyclerview">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_recyclerview_fragment_to_detail_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/detail_fragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
        android:name="info.shutterpress.idols.DetailFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail">
        <argument
            android:name="positionDatum"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="0" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

How can I use the onClick function from ListHolder with position and Int data sent to it?

Answer (score 0):

Just try use a click listener or use a lamba listener . Pass the listener from ListFragment into IdolsListAdapter. A click-event will be passed to fragment where you can navigate to DetailFragment with position

For example:

```
inner class IdolsListAdapter(var image: TypedArray?, var title: Array<String>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListHolder>() {
        
        var clickListener: (Int) -> Unit = {}

        // other code

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListHolder, position: Int) {
            var mImage = image!!.getResourceId(position, -1)
            var mTitle = title!![position]
            holder.apply {
                titleTextView.text = mTitle
                imageView.setImageResource(mImage)
            }
            holder.bind(_position)
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                 clickListener(position)
            }
        }
    }
```

In fragment:

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        // other code
        var adapter = IdolsListAdapter(image, title).apply {
            clickListener = { position -> navigateToDetailFragment(position) }
        }
        bind.idolsList.adapter = adapter
        return bind.root
    }
 
 fun navigateToDetailFragment(position: Int) {
      val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionRecyclerviewFragmentToDetailFragment().setPositionDatum(position)
      v.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for care of answering, however, same error happens. I have clean build and rebuild, and API reinstallation same. If I use bundle instead, content display, but only index 0 of the arrays assigned. Any advice for this?

Comment: I have resolved it. I have used higher order function as specified by https://www.avinsharma.com/android-recyclerview-onclick/ and moved navArgs related statement into onCreateView of DetailFragment, it displays contents very well.